# ERROR TypeError - is not a function

Tags: javascript

Intento hacer que un objeto, un círculo se mueva al presionar un botón pero que se mueva constantemente de izquierda a derecha y arriba y abajo ósea es como el funcionamiento de Pac-man del movimiento. Lo que no entiendo es porque no quiere funcionar y la verdad ya me la pase horas intentando de todo. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```
let x = 200;
let y = 200; 
let r = 30;
let mover = false; 


const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const button1 = document.getElementById("arriba");
button1.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverArribaF = true; 
  moverIzquierdaF = false;
    moverAbajoF = false; 
  moverDerechaF = false;
});

const button2 = document.getElementById("derecha");
button2.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverAbajoF = false; 
  moverDerechaF = true;
      moverArribaF = false; 
  moverIzquierdaF = false;
});

const button3 = document.getElementById("centro");
button3.addEventListener("click", 
  () => { 
    moverArribaF = false; 
    moverIzquierdaF = false;
    moverAbajoF = false; 
    moverDerechaF = false;
    orientacion = "";
    x = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
    y = canvas.clientHeight / 2;
});


const button4 = document.getElementById("izquierda");
button4.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverArribaF = false; 
  moverIzquierdaF = true;
    moverAbajoF = false; 
  moverDerechaF = false;
});

const button5 = document.getElementById("abajo");
button5.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverAbajoF = true; 
  moverDerechaF = false;
    moverArribaF = false; 
  moverIzquierdaF = false;
});

let moverArribaF = false;
let moverIzquierdaF = false;
let moverDerechaF = false;
let moverAbajoF = false;
let orientacion = "";
let xe = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
let ye = canvas.clientHeight / 2;
let re = 20;

const moverArriba = () => {
  if (y > 0) {
    y -= r;
  } else {
    y = canvas.clientHeight;
  }
};

const moverIzquierda = () => {  
  if (x > 0) {
    x -= r;
  } else {
    x = canvas.clientWidth;
  }
};

const moverAbajo = () => {  
  if (y > 0) {
    y += r;
  } else {
    y = canvas.clientHeight;
  }
};

const moverDerecha = () => {  
  if (x > 0) {
    x -= r;
  } else {
    x = canvas.clientWidth;
  }
};

const inicio = () => {
  
  if (moverArribaF === true) {
    moverArriba();
  } else if (moverIzquierdaF === true) {
    moverIzquierda();
  } 
  
  if (moverAbajoF === true) {
    moverAbajoF();
  } else if (moverDerechaF === true) {
    moverDerechaF();
  }
    
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();    
}


setInterval(inicio, 300);
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
    <br/>
    <button id="arriba">Arriba</button>
    <button id="izquierda">Izquierda</button>
    <button id="centro">Centro</button>
    <button id="derecha">Derecha</button>
    <button id="abajo">Abajo</button>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Algún error en concreto?? O simplemente no te funciona y ya esta?? Intenta darnos más datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos "deslices de teclado", por ejemplo en la función mover derecha mueves a la izquierda: disminuyes la coordenada x
Dentro de la función inicio(), en el botón derecho e izquierdo llamas a funciones que no existen como moverDerechaF, debe ser moverDerecha.
Te pongo el código completo

```js
let x = 200;
let y = 200; 
let r = 30;
let mover = false; 


const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const button1 = document.getElementById("arriba");
button1.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverArribaF = true; 
  moverIzquierdaF = false;
    moverAbajoF = false; 
  moverDerechaF = false;
});

const button2 = document.getElementById("derecha");
button2.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverAbajoF = false; 
  moverIzquierdaF = false;
  moverArribaF = false; 
  moverDerechaF = true;
  });

const button3 = document.getElementById("centro");
button3.addEventListener("click", 
  () => { 
    moverArribaF = false; 
    moverIzquierdaF = false;
    moverAbajoF = false; 
    moverDerechaF = false;
    orientacion = "";
    x = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
    y = canvas.clientHeight / 2;
});


const button4 = document.getElementById("izquierda");
button4.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverArribaF = false; 
  moverIzquierdaF = true;
    moverAbajoF = false; 
  moverDerechaF = false;
});

const button5 = document.getElementById("abajo");
button5.addEventListener("click", () => { 
  moverAbajoF = true; 
  moverDerechaF = false;
    moverArribaF = false; 
  moverIzquierdaF = false;
});

let moverArribaF = false;
let moverIzquierdaF = false;
let moverDerechaF = false;
let moverAbajoF = false;
let orientacion = "";
let xe = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
let ye = canvas.clientHeight / 2;
let re = 20;

const moverArriba = () => {
  if (y > 0) {
    y -= r;
  } else {
    y = canvas.clientHeight;
  }
};

const moverIzquierda = () => {  
  if (x > 0) {
    x -= r;
  } else {
    x = canvas.clientWidth;
  }
};

const moverAbajo = () => {  
  if (y > 0) {
    y += r;
  } else {
    y = canvas.clientHeight;
  }
};

const moverDerecha = () => {  
  if (x > 0) {
    x += r;
  } else {
    x = canvas.clientWidth;
  }
};

const inicio = () => {
  
  if (moverArribaF === true) {
    moverArriba();
  } else if (moverIzquierdaF === true) {
    moverIzquierda();
  } 
  
  if (moverAbajoF === true) {
    moverAbajo();
  } else if (moverDerechaF === true) {
    moverDerecha();
  }
    
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();    
}


setInterval(inicio, 300);
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas> 
    <br/>
    <button id="arriba">Arriba</button>
    <button id="izquierda">Izquierda</button>
    <button id="centro">Centro</button>
    <button id="derecha">Derecha</button>
    <button id="abajo">Abajo</button>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias me corregiste lo que necesitaba te lo agradezco mucho